# How to open a file on mac OSX 10.8.2 in python

Tags: python, macos, file, subprocess, popen

I am writing a python code on eclipse and want to open a file that is present in Downloads folder. I am using MAC OSX 10.8.2. I tried with `f=os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/DeletingDocs.txt")` 
and also with

```
ss=subprocess.Popen("~/Downloads/DeletingDocs.txt",shell=True)
ss.communicate()
```

I basically want to open a file in subprocess, to listen to the changes in the opened file.But, the file is not opening in either case.

Comment: The first parameter of `Popen` should be an executable, not a text file.

Comment: @cdarke ss=subprocess.Popen("~/Downloads/DeletingDocs.txt",shell=True) is working fine in windows. But in mac osx, it is not working.

Comment: Under Windows, I expect that any attempt to execute a file that is not executable will instead run the default application for opening such files. At best, this is an abuse of `Popen`, as it certainly isn't portable.

Answer (score 4):

```
from os.path import baspath, expanduser
filepath = abspath(expanduser("~/") + '/Downloads/DeletingDocs.txt')
print('Opening file', filepath)
with open(filepath, 'r') as fh:
    print(fh.read())
```

Take note of OSX file-handling tho, the IO is a bit different depending on the filetype.
For instance, a `.txt` file which under Windows would be considered a "plain text-file" is actually a compressed data-stream under OSX because OSX tries to be "smart" about the storage space.

This can literately ruin your day unless you know about it (been there, had the headache.. moved on)

When double-clicking on a `.txt` file in OSX for instance normally the text-editor pops up and what it does is call for a `os.open()` instead of accessing it on a lower level which lets OSX middle layers do `disk-area|decompression pipe|file-handle -> Texteditor` but if you access the file-object on a lower level you'll end up opening the disk-area where the file is stored and if you print the data you'll get garbage because it's not the data you'd expect.

So try using:

```
import os
fd = os.open( "foo.txt", os.O_RDONLY )
print(os.read(fd, 1024))
os.close( fd )
```

And fiddle around with the flags.
I honestly can't remember which of the two opens the file as-is from disk (`open()` or `os.open()`) but one of them makes your data look like garbage and sometimes you just get the pointer to the decompression pipe (giving you like 4 bytes of data even tho the text-file is hughe).

## If it's tracking/catching updates on a file you want

```
from time import ctime
from os.path import getmtime, expanduser, abspath
from os import walk

for root, dirs, files in walk(expanduser('~/')):
    for fname in files:
        modtime = ctime(getmtime(abspath(root + '/' + fname)))
        print('File',fname,'was last modified at',modtime)
```

And if the time differs from your last check, well then do something cool with it.
For instance, you have these libraries for Python to work with:

- [.csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)
- [.pdf](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/)
- [.odf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/odfpy)
- [.xlsx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter)

And MANY more, so instead of opening an external application as your first fix, try opening them via Python and modify to your liking instead, and only as a last resort (if even then) open external applications via Popen.

But since you requested it (sort of... erm), here's a **Popen approach**:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from os.path import abspath, expanduser
from time import sleep

run = Popen('open -t ' + abspath(expanduser('~/') + '/example.txt'), shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

##== Here's an example where you could interact with the process:
##== run.stdin.write('Hey you!\n')
##== run.stdin.flush()

while run.poll() == None:
    sleep(1)
```

## Over-explaining your job:

This will print a files contents every time it's changed.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as fh:
    import time
    while 1:
            new_data = fh.read()
            if len(new_data) > 0:
                fh.seek(0)
                print(fh.read())
            time.sleep(5)
```

**How it works:**
The regular file opener `with open() as fh` will open up the file and place it as a handle in `fh`, once you call `.read()` without any parameters it will fetch the entire contents of the file.
This in turn doesn't close the file, it simply places the "reading" pointer at the back of the file (lets say at position 50 for convenience).

So now your pointer is at character 50 in your file, at the end.
Wherever you write something in your file, that will put more data into it so the next `.read()` will fetch data from position 50+ making the `.read()` not empty, so we place the "reading" pointer back to position 0 by issuing `.seek(0)` and then we print all the data.

**Combine that with `os.path.getmtime()`** to fine any reversed changes or 1:1 ratio changes (replacing a character mis-spelling etc).

Comment: it prints the file content in console. Actually, i want to open a file as usual like that of textediter. So that i can edit the file.

Comment: it prints the file content in console. Actually, I want to open a file as usual like that of textediter. So that I can edit the file. Acutally, I want to open different file types like .odt, .csv.,.pdf and all.

Comment: You failed to mention that in your first answer. Secondly, you should open them programmatically and track changes not via a subprocess channel. The main reason it would require far less resources you checking it rather than an external application doing it. Secondly, Python has support for all those file-types you mentioned. (see my edit)

Comment: @HarishBarvekar Check the latest edit btw, it shows how to go about the Popen way without any issues (tested on my dustly old Mac book pro).

Comment: I want to listen to the changes in file that is opened. If some edit is done on file, it should call another function, till file is open. If file is closed, then it should execute next instruction. after opening file command.

Comment: @HarishBarvekar The solution is staring you in the face, but for convenience i put it down into code for you (check my last edit).

Comment: @Torxed subprocess.call(['open','-W',FileName]) opens the file in texteditor, but executes next statement only when text-editor is quit from dock forcefully. Is there ant other way to open a file and wait till file file is not closed in python

Comment: @harish Don't use `call` is a good start, use `Popen()` instead.

Comment: @Torxed file is not even opening with subprocess.Popen(['open','-W',FileName])

Comment: try:  `print(FileName,'is being opepned')` and then `x = Popen('open -W ' + FileName, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` and then `while 1: print(x.stdout.read())`

Comment: @Torxed thanx a lot for your effort. But, x = Popen('open -W ' + FileName, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) opens the file, but it executes next instruction even when the opened file is not closed. Same happens with run = Popen('open -t ' + abspath(expanduser('~/') + '/example.txt'), shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT). Sir, what I want is open the file, and then execute next instruction only when the opened file is closed by clicking on left red button.

Comment: @Torxed subprocess.call(['open','-W',FileName]) opens the file in texteditor, but executes next statement only when text-editor is quit from dock forcefully. This works what i want but issue with it is that, I have to forcefully quit texteditor from dock, and then it executes next instruction. Please suggest some as we are close to find a solution for it.

Comment: @harish Check out this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/gY1zK9US I hope the code is self-explaining because it's really simple.

Comment: @Torxed I appreciate your effort you are putting.                   x = Popen('open -W ' + FileName, shell=True, stderr=STDOUT, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
while x.poll() == None:
    print('Text editor is still open')
    sleep(0.5). File opens, then it eneters while loop. It then remains in loop even when I closed the file. For coming out of loop, I have to quit the texteditor from dock manually. It is behaving similar to subprocess.call(['open','-W',FileName]).

Comment: @Torxed What I want is after closing the file by clicking on red-cross checkbutton, it should then execute next instruction, and for it no need to quit the texteditor from dock manually.

Comment: @harish This is because you don't understand the basic functionality of the OSX system. The way it is designed is so that applications literately never truly exits unless you "remove it from the dock". What does `print(x.poll())` say when you've "closed" the application but not removed it from the dock? does it give you any status messages? Try the following: http://pastebin.com/uRauWynu Since OSX is worthless in terms of programming, and interacting with applications is very linier you're better off checking io operations of the OS and catching the operations on the file you need.

Comment: @harish and here's the docs you'll need to understand what iosnoop does: http://goo.gl/jhdU80

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40361/discussion-between-harish-and-torxed)

Comment: There is a typo in your code:
In first line "from os.path import baspath, expanduser", the baspath should be abspath

Answer (score 2):

I am hesitant to answer because this question was double-posted and is confusingly phrased, but... if you want to "open" the file in OSX using the default editor, then add the `open` command to your subprocess. This works for me:

```
subprocess.Popen("open myfile.txt",shell=True)
```

Comment: subprocess.Popen("open myfile.txt",shell=True) In this the path of file is changed. Actually the file path is python workspace on eclipse + filename. And in that location, file is not present.

Comment: You are supposed to put the path to your file in place of `myfile.txt`. The key part is adding the `open` command into the shell command. If you out the path to your file, that file should open in the GUI using the default application. But it sounds like the description of the problem is now to monitor a file for changes, and not open it? We are trying out best to guess, but maybe @Torxed has covered the most options...

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a permissions issue, if you try your code in the Python interpreter you will probably receive a "Permission denied" error from the shell when you call subprocess.Popen.  If this is the case then you will need to make the file a minimum of 700 (it's probably 644 by default) and you'll probably want 744.

Try the code in the Python interpreter and check for the "Permission denied" error, if you see that then do this in a shell:

```
chmod 744 ~/Downloads/DeletingDocs.txt
```

Then run the script.  To do it all in Python you can use os.system:

```
import os
import subprocess

filename = "~/Downloads/DeletingDocs.txt"
os.system("chmod 744 "+filename)
ss=subprocess.Popen(filename, shell=True)
ss.communicate()
```

The reason it "just works" in Windows is because Windows doesn't support file permission types (read, write and execute) in the same way as *nix systems (e.g. Linux, BSD, OS X, etc.) do.

Comment: Yes, there is "permission denied". I tried with your code, but it didn't work. I want to open a file not like printing the content in console. I want to open any file type, edit its content and save it.

Comment: In that case you probably don't want to use subprocess. Just open the files directly and manipulate them (e.g. read, write and append).

Comment: yes, thats what I am asking, how to open a file. File is not opening.I want to open a file as normal you open in windows by double-clicking on it. I am using python on mac osx.

Comment: The Python documentation [covers this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) very well, as does the [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) section on [file objects](http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/file_objects.html).  Actually, you could benefit greatly from working through Dive Into Python (a free book for learning the language), although given its age it only deals with Python 2 and not Python 3.  Still, for what you appear to want to do that will make very little difference.

Comment: thanx a lot for your response. In windows os.popen(filename) and ss=subprocess.Popen(filename, shell=True) works fine. But, I am not getting why it is not working in mac osx.

Comment: For editing the file directly, there are better ways, which the links in my previous comment point straight to.  Whereas subprocess is more for obtaining data about input and output methods to processes (including processes for accessing files).  It definitely has its uses, but manipulating the data in a file is best served with the proper IO operations.  For example, try this in the Python interpreter (when done you should have a file called foo.txt in your home directory): afile = open("~/foo.txt", "a") ; afile.write("foo bar") ; afile.close()

Comment: but why the file is not opening in general in python on mac. IT is opening in windows through same code and also the modifications you had provided

Comment: Because OS X has better file permissions than Windows does since it inherits that from BSD.  Also, subprocess is not intended to be used for writing data to files or reading data from them.  As the [subprocess documentation says](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess), it is intended to allow you "to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes."  There's nothing in there about manipulating file data, that's what [other input/output](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) functions are for.