# How to open a file on mac osx in python

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, popen

I am trying to open a file on mac in python using eclipse.

```
FileName = "/Users/fis/Desktop/installation_guide.txt"
ss = subprocess.Popen(FileName, shell=True)
ss.communicate()
```

And also `os.popen(FileName)`. But file is not opening. These codes work fine in windows. But, I don't know whats the problem with mac. I want to open a file just like double-clicking on windows to open a file and not like reading the content of file and printing in console. File is present on Desktop location on mac

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a file on mac OSX 10.8.2 in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273210/how-to-open-a-file-on-mac-osx-10-8-2-in-python)

Comment: So, you didn't get the answer you wanted in the first question so you just asked again?

Comment: @KevinDTimm yes file is still not opening. I tried a lot. Do not know whats the problem with it

Comment: related: [Open document with default application in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/434597/4279), see also [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15055133/4279). The way *to wait for the application to exit/file to be closed* might depend on the application/OS that is used to open the file i.e., you might need specialized solutions for each file type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`open` (1)](https://ss64.com/osx/open.html) command.

```
import subprocess
FileName = "/Users/fis/Desktop/installation_guide.txt"
subprocess.call(['open', FileName])
```

Comment: ss=subprocess.Popen("open '/Users/fis/Desktop/installation_guide.txt'", shell=True)
ss.wait(). File is opening but , it is not blocking. I tried with ss.communicate() also. I appreciate your suggestions

Comment: I removed, wait/ communicate(). But it is still not blocking.

Comment: @HarishBarvekar, I misunderstood your comment. Try `subprocess.call(['open', '-W', FileName])`

Comment: subprocess.call(['open', '-W', FileName]) opens the file. But control is lost after its execution. I want is open a file. Then wait till file IS OPENED i.e. control should wait. And after the opened file is closed, the control is given to next statement.

Comment: @HarishBarvekar, Using `-W` option, controll will be back to the python process once the opened program quit.

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestions. I tried with ss=subprocess.call(['open', '-W', FileName]). File is opened and when I click on red cancel button left side, file deletes. But control is not passed to next instruction till, I quit text editor from dock. Now the issue  is, I previously open a file, text editor now appears on dock. Then I again run the code, file opens. But the issue is, control will go to next instruction only when I quit the text editor from dock. In that case, I have to close the previous open file also.

Comment: @HarishBarvekar, I have no idea. Maybe you need to use AppleScript to fully control the other application.

Comment: I have no idea about apple script. Please help me in this.

Comment: @HarishBarvekar, I neither am not goot at AppleScript. How about post another question (with tag `applescript ui-automation`) ?