# How to open a file in subprocess on mac osx

Tags: python, macos, applescript, subprocess, popen

I want to open a file and wait the execution of next instruction till file is not closed. I followed the link [How to open a file on mac OSX 10.8.2 in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273210/how-to-open-a-file-on-mac-osx-10-8-2-in) python but it didn't work.

`subprocess.call(['open','-W',FileName])` opens the file in texteditor, but executes next statement only when text-editor is quit from dock forcefully, even though I closed the opened file.Means, it should execute next statement only when file is closed, and then texteditor should automatically quit from dock.
I also tried with Popen but it didn't work

```
ss=subprocess.Popen("~/Downloads/DeletingDocs.txt",shell=True)
ss.communicate()
```

Please suggest some method for it

Comment: Why did you construct your script in such a way that you have to wait for another process to exit before continuing? There is almost certainly a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving this as "EditOneAndQuit" and then do:

```
chmod +x EditOneAndQuit
```

Then start that from Python:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Start textedit in background
open "$1" &

# Wait till textedit has zero documents open
while true
do
sleep 1
docs=`osascript -e 'tell application "textedit" to get documents'`
if [ -z "$docs" ]; then
    # Kill off poor old textedit
    osascript -e 'tell application "textedit" to quit'
exit
fi
done
```

Try it from the shell first, by creating a document and editing it:

```
ls > fred.txt
./OpenOneAndQuit fred.txt
```

you should see that the script, along with textedit, exits when you close the document by clicking the red button.

Comment: Can, it can be included in python script, ie. can be included in python code.

Comment: Yes, use subprocess.call. Did you try it from the Terminal and see that the script stays running till you close the document, and then exits?

Comment: subprocess.call(['/path/to/EditOneAndExit', '/path/to/yourDoc'])

Comment: subprocess.call(['/path/to/EditOneAndExit', '/path/to/yourDoc']) causing error, I included my filename path in '/path/to/yourDoc'. What to include in '/path/to/EditOneAndExit'. Does it open file and execute next instruction only when opened file is closed.

Comment: The first parameter is the full path to wherever you saved the script I gave you. The second parameter is the full path to the document to be edited. Did you try running it from the Terminal like I suggested?

Comment: Have you got this working yet? Did you remember to do "chmod +x"? Have you got it running from the Terminal first? Feel free to contact me directly on mark at thesetchells dot com.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the file does not end the process, as you will see that the editor is still running at the top of the screen when you close the file.

Press "Cmd+Q" to exit the process.

As it seems you cannot get your users to differentiate between closing documents and closing applications, I can only suggest something VERY UGLY. Can you start another background process that uses Applescript to wait till "textedit" starts, then ask "textedit" for a list of the documents it has open. Sleep for a few seconds if there are some, then check again. When there are none, it could tell "textedit" to exit and exit itself too.

The Applescript to do this looks like this.

```
tell app "TextEdit" to get documents
```

You may need to use "osascript" to get Python to execute Applescript.

Comment: can this can be done through code, as any user when closes the file by clicking on left red button, should close file and remove texteditor from dock and also then execute next instruction.

Comment: just like you open any file through text editor. When you close the opened file, texteditor also removes from dock automatically. In that case, we will be able to open multiple file at a time by clicking on any files

Comment: Macs don't work like that. If you close a file in Microsoft Word, or Pages, or TextEdit, the editor keeps running. You can see that at the top of the screen - all the menu options relating to your word processor stay there and the word processor keeps running. Like I said, try pressing "Cmd+Q" - does that do what you want? You can't really programmatically press "Cmd+Q" because you don't know when the user has finished editing. The only way he can signal that is by closing the editor to stop the process, not by closing the file.

Comment: OK, I appreciate your suggestion, but the issue is subprocess.call(['open','-W',FileName]) executes next instruction when I forcefully quit the texteditor from dock. What I want to do is execute next instruction when closing the file by clicking on left red button, without forcefully quit the texteditor from dock

Comment: You told Python to start a process. It starts a process and will not do anything till that process ends. You can either end the process by "force quitting" it, or by quitting it properly with "Cmd+Q". Simply closing one document (with the red button) in a word processor does not end the process.

Comment: Ending subprocess by forcefully quiting from dock is not desired. Can we do something different like ss=subprocess.Popen("~/Downloads/DeletingDocs.txt",shell=True)
ss.communicate() worked on windows. Or instead of subprocess, can we do something else so that we can meet our requirement that, it should execute next instruction only when file is closed by clicking on red button and no need to go in dock.