# Blocking call while opening a file in python on osx

Tags: python, macos, cocoa, applescript, subprocess

I am using python 2.7 on osx 10.9 I want to open a file in their default file opener like TextEdit for .txt file, pdf opener for .pdf file etc. 
As file is opened, it should block i.e. I want to open a file and wait the execution of next instruction till file is not closed. I read https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html and [How to open a file in subprocess on mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689492/how-to-open-a-file-in-subprocess-on-mac-osx) and used `subprocess.call(["open","-W", FileName])`.But in this case, **even when closing the opened file, I have to manually force quit the file opener from dock location**. 
So, it causes closing of previous opened file also. 
 Suppose I have a multi-tab text editor open and I run my application. Then text file will be opened in a tab on my already-running editor. Then my program will refuse to continue until I close all of my tabs, including the ones that had nothing to do with my task. So, how to resolve this. When file is opened, I am handling the changes in the file through watchdog in a thread, reason for blocking.

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
class ChangeHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def on_any_event(self, event):
        myfunction(a, FileName, selectedFileName,b)

def filemonitor(FileName,tempLocation):

    while 1:
        global observer
        event_handler = ChangeHandler()
        observer = Observer()
        observer.schedule(event_handler, tempLocation, recursive=True)
        observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            observer.stop()
        observer.join()        

Thread(target=filemonitor,args=(FileName,tempLocation,)).start()    

subprocess.call(["open","-W", FileName])
observer.stop()

time.sleep(2)
os.remove(FileName)
```

Opening file, blocking call. Then listening to changes. When file is closed, then remove the file

Comment: Why not just continue to the next step, regardless of what the user does with the opened file? This seems like a user-hostile design to me. Suppose I have a multi-tab text editor open and I run your application. Your text file will be opened in a tab on my already-running editor. Then your program will refuse to continue until I close all of my tabs, including the ones that had nothing to do with your task.

Comment: yes, that the issue I am facing. Thats why I asked the question. I want that if I close opened file by closing red mark, process then continue without need for forcibly quitting file opener. You clearly understand my issue, now how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the deal with OSX. It doesn't close an application just because you "close" it.
OSX is intended to speed up and make ease of everything you do, there for it leaves the application as is unless you do something new with it (open a new file which open up the application or you force close it).

You can do:

```
from subprocess import Popen
handle = Popen('open -W ' + FileName, shell=True)

# Do some stuff
handle,terminate()
```

And that would shut down the application.
I really didn't understand what exactly it is you want to do because your question is quite badly written (not that i'm any bettter with my English). But if you want to wait for the application to terminate, you'd do:

```
from time import sleep
while handle.poll() is None:
    sleep(0.025)
# do something after TextEditor has shut down
```

But then again, you'd have to force:ably close the application from the dock, because again.. OSX doesn't shut down the application just because you press the close button.

What you could do is something like:

```
from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT, PIPE

watchdog = Popen('iosnoop -f ' + FileName, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
textfile = Popen('open -W ' + FileName, shell=True)

while watchdog.poll() is None:
    output = watchdog.stdout.readline()
    if 'close' in output.lower():
        break

textfile.terminate()
watchdog.terminate()
watchdog.stdout.close()
```

This would:

- Open a I/O snoop which prints all information regarding OPEN, SEEK, CLOSE etc for the filename given
- Open up the texteditor with the file you requested
- If 'CLOSE' is present in the IO Snoop, we close the texteditor

It's just an idea out of the blue but i solved similar issues with OSX this way.
THere's also [dtrace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/dtrace.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/dtrace), [iosnoop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/iosnoop.1m.html), [execsnoop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/execsnoop.1m.html)

Comment: Suppose I have a multi-tab text editor open and I run my application. Then text file will be opened in a tab on my already-running editor. Then my program will refuse to continue until I close all of my tabs(force quit), including the ones that had nothing to do with my task. So, how to resolve this.

Comment: @winterfall You don't, IMO you're programming yourself into a trap. But in the best case scenario, you use the last code i wrote in my answer. It will continue the application as soon as that particular file is closed (no matter if the editor is tabbed or not)... But you might want to ditch `textfile.terminate()`, other than that the code should be fine.

Comment: I checked both code. In watchdog code above, getting error as `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/IMP/Documents/workplace/Desk/moniterTest.py", line 8, in <module>
    if 'close' in output.lower():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'`. Even my code is terminating only when I force quit the TextEdit. My requirement is as soon as I close the opened file by clicking on red close button, then the blocking call is finished and then execute next instruction. Force quitting of file opener is not desired. Not concern where File opener still running behind or not.

Comment: I want waiting only for closing the opened file through red close button. Not waiting for closing of file opener application

Comment: @winterfall Just bloody try the code will you? :P This has nothing to do with closing the application, this has to do with the **file**, whenever the file gets closed (application can still run) this code will continue to execute...

Comment: I am getting error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/IMP/Documents/workplace/Desk/moniterTest.py", line 7, in <module>
    output == watchdog.readline()
NameError: name 'output' is not defined
When I change to output = watchdog.readline(),then getting error as 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/IMP/Documents/workplace/Desk/moniterTest.py", line 7, in <module>
    output = watchdog.readline()
AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'readline'.  Please suggest

Comment: Please see last three terminate statements as getting error as Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/IMP/Documents/workplace/Desk/moniterTest.py", line 12, in <module>
    watchdog.terminate()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1532, in terminate
    self.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1527, in send_signal
    os.kill(self.pid, sig)
OSError: [Errno 3] No such process.

Comment: And also file is opening only when I am removing textfile.terminate() statement from the code

Comment: As i have no MAC atm, you'll have to do a manual iosnoop becuase `close` might not be the keyword to look for :)

Comment: It is never going into `while watchdog.poll() is None:` It executes textfile = Popen('open -W ' + FileName, shell=True) and then jumps to `watchdog.terminate()`. I tried a lot with this issue but till now not able to find a solution

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48675/discussion-between-winterfall-and-torxed)